# Just want to add word "CHAPTER" before number of chapter but before number of section and subsection appear word "CHAPTER"

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I want to add word "CHAPTER" before number of chapter in table of content, and don't want "CHAPTER" appear before number of section and subsection. This is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\chaptername~\oldnumberline}%
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
    contents...
\end{document}
```

This code give me
[image]

How to remove word "CHAPTER" before number of section and subsection?
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code compilable i.e. a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem. This will be much more use than just a snippet. But `\numberline` is used for every line, so, obviously if you add `\chaptername` to its definition, you are going to get the value of that macro added to every line. Rather than asking how to then remove it from some lines, you'd be better to only add it to the lines you want it added to in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Use `chaptername` in `\numberline`

Use like this

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
     Chapter #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother
```

your code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
%    %
%    %

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
     Chapter #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
    contents...
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple with package  `titletoc`, which comes with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

          \titlecontents{chapter}[6em]{\bigskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
          {\contentslabel[ \chaptername~\thecontentslabel]{5.5em}}%
          {}%numberless chapters%
          {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
    contents...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example with package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
contents...
\section{Latar Belakang}
contents...
\subsection{ABCD}
contents..
\subsection{EFGH}
...
\section{Rumusan Masalah}
\vspace{0.3cm}
blablabla

\section{Tujuan Penulisan}
\vspace{0.25cm}
blablabla..

\chapter{DASAR TEORI}
contents...
\chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
contents...
\chapter{PENUTUP}
contents...
\chapter*{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
contents...
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya If you like an answer then you can upvote it. If one of the answer solves your issue then you can accept it.